# Edit SSIS connections in config file from command line

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle11g, database-migration

I generated a SSIS packed by using the SQL Server export wizard utility.

**I extract records from an Oracle 11g database and migrate them to SQL Server 2008 R2.**

Since I have many oracle databases (test, production) with the same schema, I would like to reuse the created package also for the other environments. The package would be executed via command line and ideally by changing the source and target connection strings according to the different systems.

**Is it possible to use the package .config file in order to change the source and target connection?**

If so, which are the "keywords" to ensure that a specific connection strig is used for the proper target database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a SSIS package using wizard ,select the option Don't save sensitive while saving the package

[image]

Once the package is saved ,Log in to integration service expand `MSDB` and then `Maintenance Plan` folder where you will find your SSIS package .Right Click on the `Package` and select `Run Package`

In the connection Manager tab select your datasources .

[image]

Then click on command line option .You will get the entire command to execute your package where you can modify the connection strings which you have selected above .

The command might look like

```
 /DTS "\MSDB\PackageName" /SERVER "ServerName" 
 /CONNECTION  DestinationConnectionOLEDB;"\"Data Source=localhost; 
  Initial Catalog=DBName;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;
  Auto Translate=false;\"" /CONNECTION SourceConnectionOLEDB;
  "\"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBName;Provider=SQLNCLI10;
  Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;\"" 
   /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING V
```

Now in order to execute the package using command prompt 
just add `dtexec` along with the above command.

Change the connection string to execute for different servers

Comment: I tried to run the package from command line, but I am always getting the following exception: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsCouldNotCreateManagedConnectionException: Could not create a managed connection manager." Even if I run with the dtexec.exe (32bit version) nothing changes. Some tables are created, but when it comes to run the data flow block, it throws the exception above.

Comment: I have no idea about the error .but check this link out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/392c89cb-19d1-48c8-8d54-e8ae0e75f8e8/

Comment: I already tried to use the 32bit "approach", even from BID, but with no success. I think there is something in my command line about credentials missing. Here it is my command: dtexec.exe /FILE import_data.dtsx CONNECTION DestinationConnectionOLEDB; Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=TEST; Provider=SQLNCLI10; Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false; CONNECTION SourceConnectionAdoNET;Data Source=Oracle;PASSWORD=XYZ;User ID=Ned; CHECKPOINTING OFF REPORTING EWCDI